# JSF <h:inputTextArea> problems with enter key/regex validator

Tags: html, regex, jsf

I have a `<h:inputTextArea>` with an `<f:validateRegex>` tag inside.

Whenever an enter key is pressed inside the text area for a new line and then the  submit button is pressed it shows that the textArea is invalid even though it shouldn't be invalid.

I removed the `<f:validateRegex>` tag from inside the textArea and everything worked fine so the issue is there but i do not have enough experience with regex to solve this problem so any help would be greatly appreciated, here is the part of code where i am having this problem:

```
<h:inputTextarea value="#{supportBean.userRequest.contents}"
                            id="contents" required="true" validatorMessage="#{msgs['supportform.contents.invalid']}"
                            requiredMessage="#{msgs['supportform.contents.invalid']}"
                            rows="6" >
                            <f:validateRegex pattern="\s*?[a-zA-Z-'א-ת]{2,}+.*" />
                        </h:inputTextarea>
```

**EDIT:**

The input text area is for a comment in a contact us form.

I did not create this regex pattern and i am not 100% sure of what its supposed to do but i need to make sure the user only enters english character, hebrew characters, numbers, spaces or new lines and the current pattern works very poorly.

So in order to fix this problem i need a new pattern allowing what i have described above.

Comment: What the atual regex _should_ do? Which inputs have you tried? And what do you expect?

Comment: `\s*?[a-zA-Z-'א-ת]{2,}+.*` is not a valid regex at least.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes post edited.

Comment: @melwil it is valid regex just the hebrew text turns the closing bracket right to left, it just isn't very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex allows you to achieve it.

---

Basic rules:

- `[]` It is a class. Inside it you can say what you will allow.
- `+` It means *at least one*.
- `^` It means from start.
- `$` It means the end.

---

Examples:

- `^[abc]+$` - will allow only the characters `a`, `b` and `c` from start till the end.
- `^[a-z]$` - will allow alphabetical letters from start till the end.
- `^\w+$` - will allow `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` and `_`.
- `^[\w\s\-]+$` - will allow the previous example plus spaces and `-` traces.

---

This way, you can say what do you want to allow.

Hope it helps.